# Content Scripts stylesheet leaks into the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension. The user double clicks on some term on the page and gets the data via a side panel popup.
The data I get is formatted and stored inside a div called innerDiv with class inner-div which is the child of div that is appended into the body.
The js part works fine but the css of that page overwrites my css and also, the extension stylesheet leaks into the page. It goes both ways.

```
.inner-div{
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  color: wheat;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.inner-div p, h1, h2 , h3, article{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: wheat;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
```

As you can see I've kept my CSS as specific as possible. So, there is not way that the page having dom with different classes inherit my css.

Picture of css leaking into page

[image]

Picture of dom element and the class

[image]

I cannot figure out why the extension css is leaking into the page. Please help!

EDIT :

Changed the div name to be more specific extension-inner-div according to the suggestions. The problem persists.

[image]

Manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,

    "name" : "QWiki",
    "description" : "", 
    "version" : "1.0",

    "browser_action" : {
      "default_popup" : "Wiki_Viewer.html",
      "default_title" : "QWiki"
    },

    "content_scripts" : [{
      "css": ["inject.css"],
      "matches": ["http://*/*" , "https://*/*"],
      "js" : ["jquery.min.js" , "inject.js"]
    }],

    "permissions" : [
      "activeTab",
      "https://en.wikipedia.org/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try making the selector even more specific, like `.my-extension-inner-div`. It's longer, but less likely to conflict with the page.

Comment: I could do that but why would the classes conflict when they are different. It's just some sites too, not all.

Comment: `.inner-div` is pretty generic. Chances are, those sites also have a `.inner-div`. Sites that don't have those classes aren't affected.

Comment: All that css looks extremely generic...especially when you use tag selectors

Comment: renamed it to `extension-inner-div` yet the problem persists.

Comment: Use [Shadow Dom](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom)

Comment: If you have your stylesheet listed on your  "content_scripts" on manifest.json, can you try and remove it. 
I assume  your html page is running in the background so you don't need your stylesheet added in content_scripts that way you will not have the style leaking prb

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Given the CSS you have shown, of course it is leaking into the page. You are generically applying CSS to all `h1, h2 , h3, article` elements. Is this not what you intended? If you really want to keep your CSS separate form the page, use an `<iframe>`.

Comment: @Makyen how is it generic when I'm encapsulating it in a class that does not belong to any other dom element on the page.

Comment: @user3762742, But you are not doing so. Only your `.inner-div p` selector is qualified to be under some element with the `inner-div` class. All the others are on any of the listed type of element. The `,` separates complete selectors, not selectors at some sub-level of selection. What it sounds like you wanted was `.inner-div p, .inner-div h1, .inner-div h2, .inner-div h3, .inner-div article{`. Even then, you are going to have bleed-into your elements from outside, but you won't bleed-out to elements not inside an `.inner-div`. Note: `inner-div` is too generic, as previously commented.

Comment: @Makyen thanks. So, it's my bad. I'll switch to `<iframe>` later. This is close to something I need.

Answer (score 1):

Just to bump [Beslinda N's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138552/content-scripts-stylesheet-leaks-into-the-page#comment71449396_42138552), I had this problem and it was resolved by taking that advice and removing my CSS file from `content_scripts`.

This might break some of your extension though - as you may want to style normal pages with custom CSS. To solve this problem I created two CSS files, `internal.css` and `external.css`. The internal file had all the styling for my `popup.html`, and the external had the CSS I actually wanted to apply to the extension user's DOM. Finally I referenced only `external.css` in `content_scripts`.